# Listview changes color of text in row on click

Tags: android, listview, selector

I have a list view:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    />
```

When I click a row, a textview inside that row changes it's color to black. When I select a row using keys instead of tapping this doesn't happen. The odd thing is that the row that changed it's text color when tapped, stays with black text color even when I select another row using keys (not tapping).

I don't want textview to change it's color. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Google for "listselector".

Comment: In the code above selector is transparent color.

Comment: right, sorry. But I still think it's in the listselector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing android:choiceMode="singleChoice" did it. Of course I had to overwrite methods for select/unselect list item, but at least textview is not changing it's text color.

Answer (score 0):

add android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" to your list..and also review if the 'row item layout' is using a background that has different select color states.